# Yii: How to import zii behavior LAMP

Tags: php, yii, lamp

I have recently moved my yii project from a Windows machine (XAMPP) to my Development environment in Ubuntu 14.04 (LAMP) however I have encountered an error which I never have encountered in windows before.

The error is:

> Alias "zii.Behaviors.CTimestampBehavior" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

yii folder permission is set to 755
I am not so sure if its because of the permission.

The code causing this error is from my user model where it is being called when a user sign's up/ register.

```
public function behaviors(){
    return array(
        'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
            'class' =>'zii.Behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
            'createAttribute' => 'create_time',
            'updateAttribute' => 'last_login',
            'setUpdateOnCreate' => true,
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is from how the Unix file system works. While Windows file names are case-insensitive, on Unix systems, they are case sensitive.

Here's how your code should be:

```
public function behaviors(){
    return array(
        'CTimestampBehavior' => array(
            'class' =>'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
            'createAttribute' => 'create_time',
            'updateAttribute' => 'last_login',
            'setUpdateOnCreate' => true,
        ),
    );
}
```

The major change is in this line: `'class' =>'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',`